# A question on limits.

Tags: limits

Is it possible to have $$\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)=-23$$ and $f(1)=107$?
I just don't know how to explain this and I don't even know if the above situation is possible.
Please help me.

Comment: Yes, if $f$ is not continuous you can construct those situations.

Comment: Can u please be a bit more clear?

Comment: Define a function $f$ that is constant $f(x)=-23$ for $x < 1$ and $f(1)=107$. Then the left-sided limit of $f$ when $x$ approaches $1$ is $-23$ but its value is $107$ at $x=1$.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes.

The most simple function like that is:

$$f(x)=-23\quad \text{for $x\ne 1$ and }
f(1)=107$$

Comment: So it's possible!!

Comment: Yes, it is! There is a plenty of functions!

Comment: Nice! But I have another doubt. If lim x->-17 f(x)=20, is it possible to determine f(-17)?

Comment: If you have just that condition then NO. You must have some other condition about $f$. The above answer cans help. I can define $f(1)$ as I want, for example it could be $f(1)=0$ instead of $107$.

Comment: It's only the condition that I have specified in the above comment

Comment: So, the answer is NO.

Comment: Oh good! So the reason is that sufficient properties of f are not mentioned, right?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot man!

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: Of course not!  ^_^